# New Class Object - Old Values Remain

Tags: c#

I've been doing C# for like 3-4 years now but I never really bothered with using a Class system as I never really needed it.

But now my project is gotten to the point where it would benefit from it. So I started to create and use one.

So I have an `internal` constructor that takes 2 Parameters (let's just say strings) and it stores them in private string's outside of the internal constructor.

I then `new MyClass("str1", "str2");` and use all its other public methods. (e.g. `.StartBenchmark()`)

Here's what's odd, if I have a `private string thisMustAlwaysStartAs="ThisString123456789";`
(which gets changed in the constructor to `changed123`;

When I `new MyClass()` I'm expecting `thisMustAlwaysStartAs` to start as `ThisString123456789` but it's already `changed123` yet I created a brand new instance?

(for e.x. Constructor Code would be the following, so you create 1 instance then another right after, you would get 2 MessageBox Popups, first one is the start as a string, the 2nd one is not, but how is that?)

```
MessageBox.Show(thisMustAlwaysStartAs);
thisMustAlwaysStartAs="changed123";
```

Notes:
MyClass doesn't implement IDisposable, so I'm never Disposing of it but that shouldn't matter, right?
The `thisMustAlwaysStartAs` "string" is an example, it's not actually a string, it's a CancellationTokenSource, if I Cancel() it, and make a new instance, it creates as already Cancelled. Is this possibly due to CancellationTokenSource being IDisposable meaning im meant to `Dipose` it when I'm finished with it? I know this would work, but when I create a new MyClass I'm assuming it essentially creates a brand new instance of CancellationTokenSource, not reuse one from another instance of MyClass.

Do I understand everything correctly?

**Q1: Why does CancellationTokenSource keep its `IsCancellationRequested` set to true even if I new MyClass() and check from the new instance?**

**Q2: If it's because I must `Dispose()` the CancellationTokenSource EVEN THOUGH I'm creating a brand new MyClass() why?**

**Q3: If Q2 is correct, should I create an IDisposable implementation to MyClass and `Dispose` CancellationTokenSource from that and use MyClass in a using()?**

If there is anything I'm missing or completely wrong about, Please tell me!

---

#### Show us the code

```
namespace NotEveryQuestionNeedsExamples {
    class Lazy {
        private static CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        public bool Stopped => CancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested;
        internal Lazy() {
            if(Stopped) { MessageBox.Show("This shouldn't show up"); }
            CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();//This will make Stopped return true
        }
    }
}

Testing:
new Lazy();
new Lazy();
//If you got ANY messagebox, then CancellationTokenSource somehow got the .IsCancellationRequested from the first Lazy() instance
```

This messagebox issue doesn't occur if I do `CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();` at start of `internal Lazy()`

Comment: Show us the code...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Done...

Comment: Your `CancellationTokenSource` is _static_... You could have 100 instances, and it would use the same one because it's static.

Comment: @John Is that the reason why? Could you explain what it actually does then I legit have only been using static as its a requirement for use with CEFSharp.

Comment: @MaDude A static field is a field that is shared between all instances of a class. - That's all that the static keyword does, makes the field shared between all instances.

Comment: @moreON Ah! That makes sense, essentially "stickied" to it. Gotcha. I never knew that before so I thank you for letting me know. Giving it a test without static right now.

Comment: @MaDude I can't really understand how can you be working with c# for 3-4 years without knowing this very basic stuff. I think it's probably way past time for you to read a good oop/c# tutorial.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yeah I dont believe it either tbh lmao, again though I never mess with classes e.t.c I usually just stick with basic methods right in Form1 hehe. Thanks guys it works now \(^ v ^)/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1: Why does CancellationTokenSource keep its IsCancellationRequested set to true even if I new MyClass() and check from the new instance?**

Because it's `static`, this means, for all the instances (each object created by `new`) there will only be one instance of `CancellationTokenSource` (with only one value for `IsCancellationRequested`) shared between them.
Each object gets it's own value for non static members (e.g. each with have a non-shared value for `Stopped`).

**Q2: If it's because I must Dispose() the CancellationTokenSource EVEN THOUGH I'm creating a brand new MyClass() why?**

Nope, nothing to do with dispose here, it's because it's `static`

**Q3: If Q2 is correct, should I create an IDisposable implementation to MyClass and Dispose CancellationTokenSource from that and use MyClass in a using()?**

Regardless of Q2 being incorrect, your class **really should** implement `IDisposable` to dispose of object it owns, like the instance of `CancellationTokenSource` i.e. where they are non static members.

I'm guessing `CancellationTokenSource` shouldn't be `static` on this class

See [C# - Static](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-static) for a tutorial on static, the second section *Static Members in a non static class* applies to this situation.